# Same code but output different when access as local file then from WAMP?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, ckeditor

I am stuck in a weird problem with IE when I right click open test.html with following code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2003-2013, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
-->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>API Usage &mdash; CKEditor Sample</title>
    <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>



</head>
<body>



        <textarea cols="100" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href="http://ckeditor.com/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>

        <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with an CKEditor instance.
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1');
        </script>




</body>
</html>
```

I get no black border when text is selected inside the ckeditor . But when I put the exact same code inside text.php and access through WAMP I get black border around the selected text . This problem is with only IE , for chrome and firefox it works.

Can Apache or PHP headers effect the IE output ?

Btw I am using ckeditor version 4 which can be downloaded from http://ckeditor.com/download  .

Answer (score 0):

PHP instead of plain HTML shoudn't affect IE output as PHP, once interpreted, goes to IE like plain HTML.

Opening with "Open" command forces IE to load a "file://" protocol in local context and it could be affected by some context protection (trusted sites or file context instead of http in some cases affects js, it won't work as expected or it could be limited in some functions).

Just try to open your .html thru WAMP this should work as the PHP one, even on IE

```
     try "http://localhost/test.html"
```

Otherwise you should look at the IE docs and try to understand what kind of protections/limitations occours on "file:///" protocol instead of "http://".

Hope it could help.